# AG Grid TypeScript in-line cell editing testing jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, ag-grid

I'm trying to create jest tests in order to test the functionality of my ag-grid table.

I currently have tests for expecting the default data in the grid, and testing the functionality of a button which adds an extra row of data to the grid.

I'm trying to edit one of my cells using in-line editing by simulating a double click on the cell I want to be edited. Then followed by a userEvent.type. However the cell never seems to update. I'm not sure if this is because the data hasn't been updated yet due to the asynchronous behaviour or if the simulated typing/click isn't working.

This is my test which is failing:

```html
test("tests the inline cell editing", async () => {
        const onClick = jest.fn();
        render(<DummyGrid onClick={onClick} />);

        const row = screen
            .getAllByRole("row")
            .filter((item) => item.getAttribute("row-id") === "1");
        fireEvent.doubleClick(row[1]);

        userEvent.type(row[1], "GT{enter}");

        await waitFor(() => {
            expect(screen.getByText("GT")).toBeInTheDocument();
        });
    });
```

And the following is the DummyGrid ag-grid component:

```html
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react/lib/agGridReact";
import { ColDef, ValueSetterParams } from "ag-grid-community";

import GridButton from "./GridButton";
import Car from "./car";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";

import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine-dark.css";

const initialState: Array<Car> = [
    { id: "0", make: "Toyota", modelName: "Celica", price: 35000 },
    { id: "1", make: "Ford", modelName: "Mondeo", price: 32000 },
    { id: "2", make: "Porsche", modelName: "Boxter", price: 70000 },
];

const fieldName = (name: keyof Car) => name;

function getRowNodeId(data: Car) {
    return data.id;
}

function onGridReady(params: object) {
    // console.log(params);
}

function onRowDataChanged(data: object) {
    // console.log(data);
}

const columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
    {
        headerName: "Make",
        field: fieldName("make"),
        editable: true,
    },
    {
        headerName: "Model",
        field: fieldName("modelName"),
        editable: true,
        // valueSetter: (params: ValueSetterParams) => {
        //     onRowDataChanged(params);
        // },
    },
    {
        headerName: "Price",
        field: fieldName("price"),
        editable: true,
    },
    {
        field: "Button",
        cellRenderer: "gridButton",
        cellRendererParams: {
            onClicked: function (
                id: string,
                make: string,
                modelName: string,
                price: number
            ) {
                // console.log(id, make, modelName, price);
            },
        },
    },
];

const gridOptions = {
    immutableData: true,
    suppressScrollOnNewData: true,
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    frameworkComponents: {
        gridButton: GridButton,
    },
};

interface Props {
    onClick: () => void;
}
const DummyGrid: React.FC<Props> = ({ onClick }) => {
    const [rowData, setRowData] = useState(initialState);

    function addData() {
        console.log("test");
        const newRow: Car = {
            id: "3",
            make: "Land Rover",
            modelName: "Defender",
            price: 40000,
        };
        // console.log(rowData);
        setRowData((oldData) => [...oldData, newRow]);
        onClick();
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Button data-testid="myButton" onClick={addData}>
                Add New Value
            </Button>
            <div
                className="ag-theme-alpine-dark"
                style={{ height: "300px", width: "802px" }}
            >
                <AgGridReact
                    columnDefs={columnDefs}
                    defaultColDef={{
                        sortable: true,
                    }}
                    rowData={rowData}
                    gridOptions={gridOptions}
                    onGridReady={onGridReady}
                    onRowDataChanged={onRowDataChanged}
                    getRowNodeId={getRowNodeId}
                    suppressColumnVirtualisation={true}
                ></AgGridReact>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default DummyGrid;
```

Any help or advice would be much appreciated. I have researched and found a very small amount of help on testing ag-grid with jest, and nothing on testing in-line ag-grid editing with jest, only the testing of separate buttons which update the grid content.

Answer (score 0):

To make this work try to use `userEvent.keyboard` function to update the input instead of `userEvent.type`

This test code is working for me given the following setup. This is using AG Grid v31, and v14 of @testing-library.

```
const App = () => {
    const gridRef = useRef<AgGridReact<RowData>>(null);

    const [rowData] = useState<RowData[]>([
        { make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000 },
        { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
        { make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxster', price: 72000 }
    ]);
    const [colDefs, setColDefs] = useState<ColDef<RowData>[]>([
        { field: 'make' },
        { field: 'model' },
        { field: 'price', editable: true},
    ]);

    return (
        <div className="ag-theme-quartz" style={{ height: 400, width: 600 }}>
            <AgGridReact<RowData>
                ref={gridRef}
                rowData={rowData}
                columnDefs={colDefs}
                modules={[ClientSideRowModelModule]} />
        </div>
    );
};

    test('double click cell to edit', async () => {
        render(<App />);

        let porschePrice = await screen.findByText('72000')

        // double click to enter edit mode       
        await userEvent.dblClick(porschePrice);

        let input: HTMLInputElement = within(porschePrice).getByLabelText('Input Editor');

        await userEvent.keyboard('100000');

        // press enter to save
        fireEvent.keyDown(input, { key: 'Enter', code: 'Enter' });

        porschePrice = await screen.findByText('100000')

    });
```